# DropDownList fill fails; DataValueField Always the bottom value

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I am filling my DropDownList with the following code;

```
 while (myDataReader.Read())
                {

                    DropDownList1.Items.Add(myDataReader[0].ToString());
                    DropDownList1.DataValueField = myDataReader[1].ToString();
                    DropDownList1.DataTextField = myDataReader[0].ToString();

                }
```

But regardless of what is selected in the DropDownList1, the DataValue is always the last DataValue to be read from the while loop.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using myDataReader, I bound the dropdownList to a data source

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from students", con);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

DropDownList1.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["FullName"].ToString();
DropDownList1.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["id"].ToString();

DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score -1):

So it looks like you want to use Database Column Names as the Data Value fields. But you're actually providing the Column Values, not the Column Names, as the Data Value Fields. Your code should look like this:

```
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ValueColumn"; //name of the value column, such as 'id' from the database
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "NameColumn"; //name of the descriptive column, such as 'name'
while (myDataReader.Read())
{
     //also, we removed the 'ToString' because we want to provide the datarow object, not the converted string value
     DropDownList1.Items.Add(myDataReader[0]);
}
```

Comment: On the Line that has  DropDownList1.Items.Add(myDataReader[0]); I am getting a "cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You should be using .Add(myDataReader[0].ToString(), myDataReader[1].ToString()); or something similar. See
http://forums.asp.net/t/1287909.aspx?How+to+add+items+in+Drop+Down+List+

Comment: If I try to assign it to a local variable it just returns "ValueColumn" (literal string)

Comment: Do you know what DataValueField property means? It tells a List, when bound to a Datacontext with an Enumerable set of objects, what properties on that object represent the name/value pairs in the Items collection.

Remove the DataText/DataValue field assignments, and use the .Add("","") syntax I put in my other comment.